# Is quantifiers are dichotomy?

Tags: logic

If for example this is false:

$$ \exists x \forall y(P(x,y)$$

Does it mean that

$$ \sim( \exists x \forall y(P(x,y))  $$

Is guaranteed to be true? so is there a dichotomy?

And does it flip all the quantifiers to:

$$ \forall x \exists y( (P(x,y))$$

I know that $ \exists x = \sim( \forall x(\sim P))$ but all I get is:

$$ \sim \exists x \forall y(P) = \sim \sim \forall x \forall y( \sim P) = \forall x \forall y(\sim P)$$

Where is my mistake? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you please tell me the meaning of the symbol $\sim $ ?

Comment: I believe it is negation. Use `\neg` to get the negation symbol $\neg$.

Comment: If a statement $P$ is false, its negation $\lnot P$ will be true.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Hey! thanks for the answer, I am asking a more general question which is "if we want to prove that a predicate is false we can prove the negation is true" is it right?

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: Thanks Shubham !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake lies in taking the negation.

The negation of $\exists x\forall y(P(x,y))$ is $\forall x\neg[\forall y(P(x,y))]$ since negation converts $\exists x(P)\to\forall x(\neg P)$. Now $\neg[\forall y(P(x,y))]$ becomes $\exists y(\neg P(x,y))$, giving $\forall x\exists y(\neg P(x,y))$.